# Using vsto in Outlook, How do I trigger the new mail toast/alert?

Tags: vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

Env: VS 2010 | .net 3.5 | Outlook 2007 | VSTO 3

I have an outlook addin that adds a new message type (by inheriting from PostItem). I'd like to trigger the Outlook New Mail Toast/Alert when a new message comes in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is an API in windows for creating/using your own "custom" toast messages, but no inbuilt API for controlling the appearance or frequency of the out of the box toast notification window that comes with Outlook.

Of cause if you sent an email to yourself and then deleted it, you would trigger the Toast, however I'm pretty sure this isn't the mechanism you were looking for to control the notification system.